# Usage of macros in std::string source

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm writing some c++ code that makes use of std::string.
I wanted to see how to code is written, so I went into the source code. (ctrl + left click).
I noticed, that there are macros everywhere.
The code even ends with:

```
_STD_END
// Corresponds to: #define _STD_END }
```

I get why macros are useful, and I use them for my own Log.hpp file, but I don't understand why anyone would use macros such as `_STD_END` instead of just writing `}`.

Just to clear up, my question is why he author of std::string, P.J. Plauger, decided to use macros in this way, and if I also should?

Comment: There are several implementations of `std::string`. Which one is this?

Comment: In the end of the file it says V6.50:0009

Comment: @Xerxes it may be more useful to tell us which compiler you're using, since you're probably using its standard library.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise

Comment: Standard libraries are **not** written with readability in mind. Library implementers also have to obey their own set of rules to avoid any collisions with user code and have the privilege of  giving permissions to themselves based on the platform or compiler they are working for which you certainly don't want to rely on. Learning by reading standard library implementations is not a very reliable way of learning c++.

Comment: @Xerxes -- *and if I also should?* -- Quick answer -- No.

Comment: To be very clear, if you want to learn what the standard library does, you should [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Anything more detailed than what it tells you is something that you're not supposed to worry about, as a normal programmer. Aside from basic curiosity, you shouldn't need to dig into standard library implementations unless you're seriously convinced the implementation has a bug.

Comment: While the Standard Library should not be used a a fun casual reading experience, you can learn some really neat, platform specific hacks you can keep in your back pocket until you really really (bunch more *really*s here) need them. And at the end of the day, more knowledge is always better than less. Just don't misuse that knowledge.

Comment: Usually, the reason why an end-user programmer is digging into the source of the standard library is if there is a suspicion that there is a bug in the implementation.  But even then, that requires the end-user programmer to have C++ skills that are close to, if not equivalent to the author of the library to do such investigation, plus they need to have a version of the standard document to verify the claim that a bug exists.   If you're just a programmer using `std::string`, there is practically little  reason to dig into the internals of `std::string`.

Comment: Look at the copyright date on that header file: 1992. The original STL [was not in a namespace](http://stepanovpapers.com/STL/DOC.PDF). The macros permit the same header file to be used in either "global namespace mode' or "`std` namespace mode" by changing a handful of `#define`s.

Comment: Some implementations may use an inline namespace inside of namespace std (say `std::__1`) and closing would require `}}`.

Answer (score 27):

That’s the Dinkumware library, which Microsoft licenses (although they've recently taken over full maintenance of their version). The `_STD_BEGIN` and `_STD_END` macros are used for customizing the `std` namespace. Some compilers don't (didn't?) support namespaces; for those compilers, the macro expansions are empty. Some compilers need some indirection, and those macros expand into directives that put the code into an implementor-specific namespace (i.e., a namespace whose name begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter), which may or may not be complemented by a using-directive to pull the contents of that namespace into `std`. And in many cases they expand into the obvious, ordinary `namespace std {` and `}`, respectively.

In short, they're about configurability for a multi-platform library implementation.

I worked for Dinkumware for quite a few years, so I have first-hand knowledge.